# Requiring mathjs

Tags: javascript, mathjs

I try to include the mathjs library into my project for the atan2(). When i try to include the folder that i installed using npm install @types/mathjs by `var Math = require('mathjs/main/es5/index');` it throws an error that it is moved and i have to include mathjs or mathjs/lib/cjs/index.js instead. This however does not work as well. So how do i include the mathjs library?

> *The file "mathjs/main/es5/index.js" has been moved since
> mathjs@8.0.0. Please load "mathjs" or "mathjs/lib/cjs/index.js"
> instead.*

Comment: I don't know the answer to what you've asked, but [vanilla JS has an `atan2` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2).

Comment: try const Math = require('mathjs');

Comment: I tried const Math = require('mathjs'); did not work, 

For Nodejs v12.13.1 and Javascript (V8) 7.7.299.13-node.16 it returns a ReferenceError: atan2 is not defined

Answer (score 0):

What you have installed are the typings only you need the package itself that @types/mathjs depends to as well.

```
npm i mathjs
npm i -D @types/mathjs
```

then you can import from 'mathjs' like so

```
import { max, pi, acos } from 'mathjs'
```